# Pattern for Retrieving Single Value from Angular 4 based Service

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to build an Angular 4 based service (backed by a C#-based RESTful API) which will allow for storing and retrieval of web-application wide settings. Something like a key-value pair based lookup for all common application settings.

The idea is this:

1. Retrieve all settings on start of the application from the C# WebApi based RESTful service into a client-side JavaScript array and stored in the Angular 4 service.
2. If any specific setting is needed, first look in the locally retrieved array for said setting and return that.
3. If said setting is not found, make a call to the previously mentioned WebAPI service for that specific setting to see if it is available and retrieve that. Also, push said retrieved setting in the client-side array so I don't have to make the call again until needed.

The problem I am having is this:

I want to return an Observable, even if I have the setting in the array locally, so that I can handle the situation of the web application having to wait for the setting to be retrieved.

I also want to handle situations where the API call for the specific setting fails.

See below for what I have now, any help appreciated.

```
'use strict';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { EmptyObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/EmptyObservable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import { SettingAPIURLs } from '../global.urls';
import * as Interfaces from "../interfaces/models.interface";
import * as Classes from "../classes/models.classes";

@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {
    private _settings: BehaviorSubject<Classes.Setting[]>;

    private settingDataStore: {
        settings: Classes.Setting[]
    }

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.settingDataStore = { settings: [] }
    }

    loadSettings() {
        this.http.get(SettingAPIURLs.GetSettings)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.settingDataStore.settings = data;
                this._settings.next(Object.assign({}, this.settingDataStore).settings);
            }, error => {
                console.log("There were errors in attempting to retrieve the web application's settings: " + error);
            });
    }

    get CurrentSettings() {
        return this._settings.asObservable().share();
    }

    retrieveSetting(SettingName: string): Observable<Classes.Setting> {

        /*

        I am lost as to what to do here.

        */

        let returnedObservable: Observable<Classes.Setting> = new Observable<Classes.Setting>();
        if (typeof (SettingName) === "undefined" || SettingName === null) {
            return new EmptyObservable();
        }
        this.http.get(SettingAPIURLs.GetSetting + "?SettingName=" + SettingName)
            .map(response => response.json())
            .first();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a built in solution for your problem called resolve.  This article explains how to use it:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

The idea is that you have the data for the page loaded before even running the logic for the page.

The basic implementation is that you need to write a resolver that will go ahead and make your settings api call.  Then you just need to hookup your routing to start using the resolver.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly , you want to send the setting if it exists else do http call . I am assuming your settings object is a key-value pair object. I am not sure why you have it is an array.

You can do something like this

```
// extract fetch part separately . If settings exist return it or do http call
fetchSettings(){  
    return this._settings.asObservable
        .flatMap(settings => settings ? 
             Observable.of(settings) :        
             this.http.get(SettingAPIURLs.GetSettings)
                .map(response => response.json())
                .do(data => {
                    this.settingDataStore.settings = data;
                    this._settings.next(
                       Object.assign(
                             {}, 
                             this.settingDataStore).settings);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("..... " + error);
        });
}

loadSettings(){
   this.fetchSettings.subscribe(data => {
       console.log('load Settings success', data);     
   });
}

retrieveSetting(SettingName: string): Observable<Classes.Setting> {
    this.fetchSettings()
        .flatMap(settings => settings[SettingName]? 
             Observable.of(settings[SettingName]) : 
             this.http.get(SettingAPIURLs.GetSetting +
                             "?SettingName=" + SettingName)
                  .map(response => response.json())
                  .do(res=> this._settings.value[SettingName] = res)
       );
}
```

If any of the above HTTP calls fail you will get an exception which you can handle in the component like this :

```
this.settingsService.retrieveSetting().subscribe(successFunction, failureFunction);
```

You can either show error message to user or consider it as blank based on your site requirements.